# Mapping Exception when trying out the Symfony2 example from the cookbook

Tags: php, symfony, doctrine-orm

I just started learning Symfony2 and I'm following the examples from "The Cookbook" from Symfony's website.

When trying the code from the chapter about loading users from database (Entity Provider) [(Link to the chapter)](http://symfony.com/doc/current/cookbook/security/entity_provider.html) I get the following error:

```
MappingException: Class Acme\UserBundle\Entity\User is not a valid entity or mapped super class.
```

... and can't find out wthat I am doing wrong. I do think I followed all the steps provided in the chapter.

Thanks for any help,

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I finally found the problem when revising step by step the whole code.

I forgot to register UserBundle in AppKernel.php.

Answer (score 0):

I have the same problem. I looked at [symfony+Mapping error](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15197183/symfonymapping-error) but that solution not works for me. Then I found, that Michi solution works https://stackoverflow.com/a/10935672/2910183

So, here is what I do at all:

1. register bundle in `AppKernel.php`:

   `new Acme\UserBundle\AcmeUserBundle(),`
2. create this bundle (it is just a copy of FOS\UserBundle\FOSUserBundle) and save as `src/Acme/UserBundle/AcmeUserBundle.php`

   `<?php`
   `namespace Acme\UserBundle;`
   `use Symfony\Component\HttpKernel\Bundle\Bundle;`
   `use Symfony\Component\DependencyInjection\ContainerBuilder;`
   `use Doctrine\Bundle\DoctrineBundle\DependencyInjection\Compiler\DoctrineOrmMappingsPass;`
   `use Doctrine\Bundle\MongoDBBundle\DependencyInjection\Compiler\DoctrineMongoDBMappingsPass;`
   `use Doctrine\Bundle\CouchDBBundle\DependencyInjection\Compiler\DoctrineCouchDBMappingsPass;`
   `class AcmeUserBundle extends Bundle {`
   `}`