# symfony+Mapping error

Tags: symfony, symfony-2.1, symfony-2.2

I am implementing the FOSUser module in my symfony i have created and configure all file as the tutorial.here is my config.yml file for mapping.

```
 namespace Acme\UserBundle\Entity;

 use FOS\UserBundle\Entity\User as BaseUser;
 use Doctrine\ORM\Mapping as ORM;


 class User extends BaseUser
 {

protected $id;

public function __construct()
{
    parent::__construct();
    // your own logic
}
}
```

it is showing the following error ..

```
 MappingException: The class 'Acme\UserBundle\Entity\User' 
was not found in the chain configured namespaces FOS\UserBundle\Entity
```

here is my config.yml file where i mention the autoloding. still it not working.

```
      imports:
- { resource: parameters.yml }
- { resource: security.yml }

  framework:
 #esi:             ~
 #translator:      { fallback: %locale% }
 secret:          %secret%
 router:
    resource: "%kernel.root_dir%/config/routing.yml"
    strict_requirements: %kernel.debug%
form:            ~
csrf_protection: ~
validation:      { enable_annotations: true }
templating:
    engines: ['twig']
    #assets_version: SomeVersionScheme
default_locale:  "%locale%"
trusted_proxies: ~
session:         ~
fragments:       ~

# Twig Configuration
twig:
debug:            %kernel.debug%
strict_variables: %kernel.debug%

 # Assetic Configuration
 assetic:
debug:          %kernel.debug%
use_controller: false
bundles:        [ ]
#java: /usr/bin/java
filters:
    cssrewrite: ~
    #closure:
    #    jar: %kernel.root_dir%/Resources/java/compiler.jar
    #yui_css:
    #    jar: %kernel.root_dir%/Resources/java/yuicompressor-2.4.7.jar

  # Doctrine Configuration
doctrine:
dbal:
    driver:   %database_driver%
    host:     %database_host%
    port:     %database_port%
    dbname:   %database_name%
    user:     %database_user%
    password: %database_password%
    charset:  UTF8
    # if using pdo_sqlite as your database driver, add the path in parameters.yml
    # e.g. database_path: %kernel.root_dir%/data/data.db3
    # path:     %database_path%

orm:
    auto_generate_proxy_classes: %kernel.debug%
    auto_mapping: true

# Swiftmailer Configuration
swiftmailer:
transport: %mailer_transport%
host:      %mailer_host%
username:  %mailer_user%
password:  %mailer_password%
spool:     { type: memory }
fos_user:
db_driver: orm 
firewall_name: main
user_class: Acme\UserBundle\Entity\User
```

Comment: sorry buddy not according to indentation of stack overflow but the important is error i will getting. thanks

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Ok, this should be easy. You need to, either enable `auto_mapping` in your `config.yml` or to manually specify "AcmeUserBundle: ~" there:

1) with auto_mapping

```
doctrine:
    orm:
        auto_mapping: true
```

2) without auto_mapping

```
doctrine:
    orm:     
        mappings:
            AcmeUserBundle: ~
```

Notice that if you are having multiple entity managers you won't be able to use `auto_mapping` feature.
Hope this helps!

Comment: this is my confing.yml pls look at it

Comment: i have mention auto loding: true but still there is some error coming

Comment: Ah so you do have `auto_mapping` enabled. Can you try turning it off and manually adding those bundles? Don't forget to add `FOSUserBundle` as well

Comment: after changing as u tell get new erro "MappingException: Class "Acme\UserBundle\Entity\User" sub class of "FOS\UserBundle\Entity\User" is not a valid entity or mapped super class."

Comment: I assume you've managed to resolve an issue. Can you write what was the cause? :)

Comment: sorry for late replay. yes the problem is auto_mapping. as soon as i did manually it is working fine now. so thanks once again.

Answer (score 3):

It is also can help:

Add into your app/AppKernel.php:

```
...
new Acme\UserBundle\AcmeUserBundle(),
...
```

Comment: Yes! I was running into the same problem. I just created a brand new bundle for the game I'm doing (Emperors of the Dynasty), and I located the User class under `namespace Xmontero\Emperors\UserBundle\Entity;` nevertheless following the tutorial, I was concentrated in adding the `FOSUserBundle` into the kernel and I completely forgot to add my `new Xmontero\Emperors\UserBundle\XmonteroEmperorsUserBundle(),` into the `AppKernel.php` - 3 years working with SF2 and forgetting something like this! ow man! not possible!!!

Answer (score 0):

Add the following line to your `app/AppKernel.php` file's bundle array:

```
new FOS\UserBundle\FOSUserBundle()
```

This is to register that namespace for Symfony.

Answer (score 0):

solucion for me:

change in ../Entity/User.php

namespace Acme\UserBundle\Entity;    with  namespace Acme\Bundle\UserBundle\Entity;

and in app/config.yml change

user_class: Acme\UserBundle\Entity\User    with
user_class: Acme\Bundle\UserBundle\Entity\User

Regards, Amic